# Why does the limit for $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} x^{-2}(x-3)^3$ not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have been told that the limit of $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} x^{-2}(x-3)^3$ does not exist.

However, it seems to me that after two applications of l'Hôpital, the limit should be $-9$

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} {{(x-3)^3}\over{x^2}}$$

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} {3{(x-3)^2}\over{2x}}$$

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} {6{(x-3)}\over{2}}=-9$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule You don't have $\lim_{x\to 0} (x-3)^3 = 0$, and thus don't satisfy the assumptions.

Comment: Using L'Hospital this way would give $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+1}x=1$ !?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are applying L'Hopital's rule to a quotient which is *not* an indeterminate form, since $\lim_{x\to0}(x-3)^3=-27$.

As a simpler example, consider$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-1}{x-2}.$$I suppose that you agree that this limit is $\frac12$. But if you apply L'Hopital's rule, then you will get $1$.

Comment: So why is is not simply $-\infty$ if the denominator approaches $0$?

Comment: Well, it *is* $-\infty$. The limit doesn't exist in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @agblt I've added more details. I hope that this will make things clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use L'Hôpital because $(x-3)^3$ doesn't go to 0 as $x\to0$.

In order to use L'Hôpital, you need that both the numerator and denominator go to $0$ or $\infty$ as $x\to0$.

This limit does not exist because the numerator goes to $-27$ and the denominator goes to $0$. Thus, the function is not bounded and the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *proper* rational function (i.e., a quotient of two polynomials with no common factors), and for these types of functions, finite limits fail to exist wherever they are undefined (i.e., whenever the denominator vanishes). This happens because for these types of rational functions, the numerator approaches a nonzero quantity while the denominator approaches zero at the point where they fail to exist, so that the quotient approaches $\pm\infty$ at such points, the appropriate sign of $\infty$ depending on other factors.

L'hopitals is useful only for calculating indeterminate limits; i.e., when both numerator and denominator approach $0,$ or both approach $\pm\infty,$ like the (improper) rational function $$\frac{x-1}{x-1}$$ near $1,$ for example, where both terms approach $0,$ but L'hopitals is not actually needed here since this is the function that is constantly $1$ everywhere except $1,$ where it is not defined. Thus, the limit at $1$ is obviously $1$. However, L'hopitals is used for cases where such observations are not so obvious; i.e., non-elementary indeterminate limits.